# How can I get the topic id when creating a topic if it hasn't been created yet?

Tags: php

Basically, I'm working on these forums in PHP and I'm making it so that when you create a topic, it will update the forum's last post saying that the last post made was that topic. The issue is, I'm trying to make it so they can click a link and go to it but how am I supposed to get the topic id if it hasn't been created yet?

Comment: I'm a coder not a magician, so I can't see over your shoulders and see your code.

Comment: more description needed

Comment: well, how should PHP time travel? If they click to create a group, then you can't have a link to the group that they haven't created yet, so redirect  `random page -> create_group.php -> group.php?id=$id_of_new_group`

Comment: @MarcB *well, how should PHP time travel?* I thought it's a new feature from PHP 7, isn't it :)?

Comment: They removed it in PHP 43 due to the paradox problem and that nasty incident off the Hawaiian coast. thankfully I didn't upgrade from 42 so I can still use `Tardis::jump()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a random $codeTopic attribute that you know before your id is created and send the code attribute instead of the id (do not forget to add your $codeTopic to the database)